# use getPosNumber() with JOptionPane

Tags: java

I have been using Scanner to use this code, but I want to use JOptionPane to use this code, with getPosNumber. I tried compareTo(), but it's not working. Thanks!

```
int height;
int length;

length = getPosNumber("What is the length of the rectangle?");
height = getPosNumber("What is the height of the rectangle?");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
length =  getPosNumber( Integer.parseInt( JOptionPane.showInputDialog( "What is the length of the rectangle?")));
```

Refer to the API : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html